# How to test a second order logic argument for validity

Tags: logic

I'm doing some research on second order logic and I'd like to write down a proof for the following argument:

[image: argument 1]

where `x` is a first order variable and `P` and `Q` are predicate symbols.

A plain english instance of the argument would be something like

> All men are mortals, so the property of being human has the property of being mortal

This looks an invalid argument to me, but I'd like a formal proof of its invalidity. I'm looking, for example, for a way to extend the finite universe method to second order arguments, but any formal proof would be good, either semantic or syntactic.

Comment: Are you working from some particular textbook? It would help to know some of the details of the system you're working within.

Comment: @Dennis I'm now in the process of searching for a textbook which provides a (simple) second order logic system. I asked here before finding it because maybe it was trivial to extend some first order method and someone already knew how to do it. I will update the quesion as soon as I find a system suited for the task. If you have advices on textbooks please share them, they're very welcome.

Comment: My first concern is that Q(P) might not be well-formed depending on how the recursive definition of a well-formed formula is laid out. I would naturally read it as a predicating a third-order variable (Q) of P.

Comment: I gave a answer assuming a translation of second-order logic into set theory. I'm still not sure I understand what Q(P) means, though, so it might be way off-base.

Comment: Take a look at [this SEP article on the semantics for Second-Order Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#2). After a quick brush-up I'm fairly sure that Q(P) won't be well-formed if both P and Q are meant to be second-order variables. Also, your statement doesn't contain any second-order quantifiers, so it's a bit odd to call it second-order. The only sense in which it is second-order, is that you have predicates applying to predicates.

Comment: according to [Barwise&Etchemendy](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FLanguage-Proof-Logic-David-Barker-Plummer%2Fdp%2F1575866323&ei=I8FdUaz5MMjUsgbuhoHIDQ&usg=AFQjCNE3hVQFxdhQIEbNTwaw4R6wwnKUOA&sig2=3FYbLuS5dKxFm08_qS-tzA&bvm=bv.44770516,d.Yms)
`P(Q)` is a well formed formula in second order logic, so I don't think there is a problem of well-formedness. Their example is `Shape(Cube)`, i.e. the property of being a cube has the property of being a shape.

Comment: I'll have to check out that book when I get home (do you have a page number for that reference to save me some digging?), but that still reads like a third-order statement. Quantifying over properties of individuals gets you to second-order logic, third-order logic _just is_ quantifying over properties of properties, fourth-order properties of (properties of properties), etc.

Comment: nevermind, what I was reading was not Barwise&Etchemendy but [this](http://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/120/SecondOrder.pdf). I confused it for the Barwise textbook because they use the same predicates (Cube, Tet, etc.). Anyway, there it says that in second order logic is possible to predicate something o a predicate. 
I'm not sure I understand why you claim we are quantifying over properties of properties, where does this quantification takes place in my example?

Comment: looks like you're right, `Q` is in fact a super predicate and requires a third order logic. I still don't understand why super-predicates requires to jump to the next order, but it seems my original question was misleading. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Try asking another question about the meaning of "first-order" vs. "second-order", etc. I gave a bit of answer earlier, but the comments here isn't a good place for a complete answer. I might edit my answer to point out the error and explain a bit of the difference, though.

Comment: Yep. of course you can consider that as a third order argument and extend some proof method accordingly, But this would be a different question of course.

BTW, should we say that the author of the linked pdf was implicitly referring to higher order logic in general and not specifically to second order logic? Or maybe it is a different naming convention? I just read that some scholars consider quantification over super-predicates as fourth order logic, while other take it as third order logic.

Comment: 1. From the universal instantiation P(P)->Q(P) you cannot derive Q(P), don't you need P(P) as additional premise? 2. Which higher-order logic? In a predicative SOL with types P(P) is not allowed, you need an impredicative SOL with restricted comprehension principle - restricted, because otherwise you get the Paradox of Predication.

Comment: Dcmst, you should probably just ask another question on first-order vs. higher-order logics at this point. Comments are getting pretty long here.

Comment: 2. all higher order logics. Since the author of the pdf uses `P(P)` while speaking of second order logic, it may be that he want to talk about higher order logic in general, i.e. all non first order logic. Or it may be the uses "second order" in a different sense, including super-predicates. About the paradox, yes, if you look at the pdf i linked above an example of `P(P)` is used exactly to show how the paradox arises. But the discussion was about well-formedness in relation to the used logic.

Comment: yeah sorry, I will asap.

Comment: All higher order logics? Then you ask many questions at once... In a HOL with type hierarchy P(P) is not well-formed, hence the argument is not valid. In an untyped HOL P(P) might be well-formed, whether the argument goes through or not (with the additional premise) depends on the comprehension principle of the logic in question.

Comment: and this is exactly what we achieved with the previous discussion :) You may want to join the coming up question about first vs. higher order logics, will be posted in a while.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proof relying on a translation of second-order logic into set theory.

Read "Px" as [image] and likewise for Qx. What the condition requires then, is that P is a subset of Q, so [image: http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$P%20\subseteq%20Q$].

Now, if Q(P) is to be read in the same way (which I think it shouldn't, it reads most naturally as a statement in *third-order* logic), then it states that [image], but clearly this doesn't follow from P being a subset of Q.

Here is a description of a countermodel (well really, a whole *class* of countermodels since I don't specify a domain): suppose that our model assigns the same members to P and Q, so that P=Q. In that case it will be true that P is a subset of Q but it will be false that P is a member of Q, since no set is a member of itself.